# Angular 6 Component class Split file

Tags: angular, components

How can i split one component class into multiple files?

Imagine this component :

```
//main.ts
@Component({
  selector: "sg-page-main",
  templateUrl: "main.html",
})

export class MainPageComponent {
 public b : number = 41;

  public aff(): void {console.log(this.b)}
  public increment(): void {this.b=this.b+1}
}
```

I want to put the function "increment" into another file. 
In my project i have more than 50 functions in the component, they all use "this" scope.

Comment: Instead of using global variables from within the function, you could pass them as parameters, making the function pure (if possible). Second, you can create one or more services and inject them in the constructor of your component.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I need to keep the class "global" variable because those variables are directly bind to the template.

Comment: I see. Still, you can make a service and move your functions which belong together there.